# Booking issues with Israir Airlines

Tags: air-travel, bookings, israel, israir-airlines

I booked a domestic flight from Eilat to Tel Aviv in Israel through Israir Airlines, directly on their website (www.israirairlines.com).

At the end of the booking process there were security certificate errors and I got the following message:

> Thank you for choosing Israir
>   Your order request number is *realnumberhere*
>   Your order status will be sent to you shortly
>   Your reservation is pending approval

To this date I haven't received any email. However, the amount due (126 USD) has been charged on my credit card!

I have already written them two emails using the contact form on their website as well as tried calling them on the phone number provided. There was no option to get a human operator and all the automated options provided no help.

So my question is how to proceed here? How can I get in touch with someone from Israir?

Comment: Just making sure, you did check your spam mail folder? When was the booking and how much time till the flight?

Comment: Yes, all checked. The booking was on Oct 4th and the flight is on Nov 10th.

Comment: They do have twitter: https://twitter.com/ISRAIR_Group and they also have a facebook presence that seems fairly responsive. Finally you could try to call their airport presences if you can get hold of these numbers.

Comment: Their Twitter account has last been used 6 years ago, and their Facebook does not seem like it is responsive.
I now found some email addresses on the google translated Hebrew website israir.co.il

Comment: I would probably just phone my credit card company, and have the charge reversed. Visa or MC will agree with you completely, if, there is *no way to contact* the company.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering (and +1), however [their facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Israir/?ref=br_rs) tells me *"Typically replies within an hour"* if you do send them a message. You are right about the twitter one of course. Do come back to tell us how the flight turned out :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem for a flight in december. I sent an email 6 days ago to site@israir.co.il and Isranet@israir.co.il but so far no answer

Answer (score 6):

I finally got an official confirmation document. No e-ticket or things like that, but maybe that's just how it works with them.

What I did I put the Hebrew website of Israir (israir.co.il) into Google Translator and found some email addresses on their 'About' page (http://www.israir.co.il/Packages/PackageHome.aspx?boneid=2439). I chose the Director of Direct Marketing.

I got a reply about 20 hours later, but only the document, no personal reply. Let's see how the flight turns out...

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in addition to a national event - the Tel Aviv - Eilat line is tiny, and it's more like a bus than like an actual flight.

Comment: It might have been Yom Kippur on the time I posted the question, but that was already 10 days after I had bought the tickets. Anyways, the flight went very well. The flight was indeed a rather small hop, but the airline was very nice, we even got water. The view was tremendous (Dead Sea and Jerusalem) and we even flew in a Boeing 737 which was fully booked (so no bus). All in all I can totally recommend Israir on the relation I traveled. Only Eilat Airport is super tiny and announcements are in Hebrew only. But they are getting a new airport in 2017.